# Unknown module(s): 'nwt_base'

Tags: magento2

This is my composer code , I do now know why I am getting unknow module error.
Please let me know

```
{
      "name": "nwt/base",
      "description": "NWT Base module",
      "type": "magento2-module",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "license": "NWTCL 1.0",
      "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
      },
      "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
          "NWT\\Base\\": ""
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is registration.php, I did all thing , cache clean , flash etc , but error is comming

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @category    NWT
 * @package     NWT_Base
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015 Nordic Web Team ( http://nordicwebteam.se/ )
 * @license     NWT Commercial License (NWTCL 1.0)
 *
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'NWT_Base',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange :). Can you please update question give details what error is giving, so we can help you out. Thanks

Comment: Have you create module.xml file?

Comment: yes I have created